# Modern times-like replacement containing text & math glyphs for use with pdftex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, times, stix

I am currently writing a manuscript for a journal which encourages authors to submit initial PDF using a "times-like" font for both text and math. The journal's technical staff told me that the final article would be typeset using some proprietary fonts for which the publisher have licenses for.

I have already looked at `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` which have been recommended as the standard replacement for new articles since the turn of last decade or so (2010-ish). However, with the advent of the `stix2` and `xits` fonts, I wonder if

- they can be considered times-"like" (I don't necessarily need a times-"clone")
- both text and math glyphs of the font are available for use under pdftex.

Any extra features like true small-caps would be a mere bonus. Can the community please provide an analysis of suitability of these modern crop of fonts for my use-case?

Comment: Why do you care? If they retypeset your document your version is only a draft.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am allowed to self-archive my submitted version and want to use the best available choice of times-like font for my pdf

Comment: Does https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html help? Note that `xits` does not work with `pdftex`.

Comment: `stix2` is no longer times-like, but `stix` is. For better small caps, you may consider the very new `step`.